# Asp.Net TextBox setting TextMode to Number causes Text to be blank

Tags: asp.net, textbox

I've got an `ASP.NET` webpage with a `TextBox` on it.

When the page is submitted, if the `TextMode` of the `TextBox` is `number` the `Text` value is blank, despite the box having characters in it.

If I remove the `TextMode="number"` attribute, it works fine.

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="textBoxRMAnumber" TextMode="number" min="00000" max="99999" MaxLength="5" Width="216" />
```

EDIT:
The javascript emitted for the page includes this:

```
    if (tagName === 'INPUT') {
        var type = element.type;
        if ((type === 'text') ||
            (type === 'password') ||
            (type === 'hidden') ||
            (((type === 'checkbox') || (type === 'radio')) && element.checked)) {
            formBody.append(encodeURIComponent(name));
            formBody.append('=');
            formBody.append(encodeURIComponent(element.value));
            formBody.append('&');
        }
```

As you can see, it ignores 'number' type.

Any ideas, please?

Comment: I haven't seen such issue before.Could you share your code.

Comment: OP edited to add offending line of code...

Comment: Tried your TextBox but could not replicate the problem. I get a value on page submit. Maybe there is some javascript interfering?

Comment: I am not able to reproduce your problem. please let us know how you are posting your page and your code behind code...

Comment: Ok, I found out why. The flaky MS javascript doesn't handle a type of 'number' - see code snippet added to OP... Using .NET framework 4.5